# How to use grunt-usemin in PHP projects?

Tags: php, gruntjs, grunt-usemin, grunt-contrib-concat

All the tutorials on optimizing website assets with grunt and grunt-usemin are based on the `src -> dist` deploy strategy. basically processing the items in your `src` folder and compiles them into the `dist` folder.

But PHP doesn't work this way. It isn't compiled and "distributed". The source and target page are the same. Which makes it a destructive process.

How do you work around this? Any tips on using Grunt in PHP project in general?

Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do something similar. We created an index.src.html with the non-minized sources, and create an index.html from this file using usemin, and we have a "proxy" php file which opens the index.html if it exists (which means we are in the production environment and the assets are built), otherwise the index.src.html if the assets haven't been built or we are in a development environment. The main idea is to separate the important parts for usemin to a different file.

Answer (score 0):

The usermin plugin is for preparing static assets (concatenate, minimise,...). Static means the server gives the same content for everybody. This constraint doesn't apply to PHP...

If you would like to use this tools to optimize your php generated pages assets, you should create input files which can be parse-able by usermin. For example you can collect the javascript/css file references into a template or a different php/html, and you include/use this file where you need, and after the build you use the usermin parsed version of it.

Comment: my assets are static. i simply link it inside a PHP file (let say: template.php). usemin works just like you said. but it also changes the links in template.php into the optimized version. which is good, but not good, because it changes the markup inside template.php.

i hope you understand what i mean. sorry if i'm not too clear with that explanation.

Comment: We do something similar. We created an index.src.html with the non-minized sources, and create an index.html from this file using usemin, and we have a "proxy" php file which opens the index.html if it exists (which means we are in the production environment and the assets are built), otherwise the index.src.html if the assets haven't been built or we are in a development environment. The main idea is to separate the "things" important for usemin to a different file.

Comment: that makes more sense now. i have to ask my backend devs to do this. can it be done inside CodeIgniter (or similar frameworks)?

Comment: I've talked to my devs about this. And they say it can be done. Can you post your comment again as a different answer so i can accept it.

Comment: I posted a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal approach would take advantage of the dynamic nature of PHP to make the "distribution" URL replacement. The process would be:

- Your build tool creates some kind of manifest or machine readable file with changes applied. Some tools, as [gulp-rev](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-rev) will do this for you.
- [Read the manifest from PHP and replace the resource URLs with the final ones](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-rev/blob/master/integration.md#approach-3---php-reads-the-manifest-and-provides-asset-names).